# VBA "store" a workbook in a global variable

Tags: excel, vba, csv, global-variables, fileopendialog

I'm trying to work out if it's possible to open a workbook using the file open dialog box and "store" it in a global variable so that it can be accessed by several subroutines.

I have `Workbooks.Open Filename:=FileToOpen` which works fine to open a workbook and I have declared a public variable like `Public wb As Workbookbook`. But when I try to assign one to t'other by doing `wb=Workbooks.Open Filename:=FileToOpen` or `Set wb=Workbooks.Open Filename:=FileToOpen` I get "Compile error. Expected end of statement" highlighting the `Filename`

Can anyone tell me if this is possible and if so the best way to approach it??

(Basically what I'm trying to achieve is to be able run a small piece of VBA that rearranges data in a csv file in the most "fool proof" (user proof) way possible. As you can't make VBA standalone .exe I was thinking: auto run a macro that opens a userform with a single button. Click the button and choose a csv, my code runs, saves the csv and closes it. Any other suggestions for this appreciated!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trying to assign result to variable, you should use parentheses:

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileToOpen)
```